# Find and delete Discord webhook message

Tags: http, discord, webhooks

I'm using a Discord webhook to send information which may later be invalidated, so I want to be able to delete it. To do this i use these endpoints:

First i make a post request to send a message:

`POST /webhooks/{webhook.id}/{webhook.token}`

And then i want to do a delete request to remove the message again:

`DELETE /webhooks/{webhook.id}/{webhook.token}/messages/{message.id}`

However I don't have the ID of the message i want to delete, since no response is given to the first POST request which is always an empty 204 response. Is it possible to get the message id?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A get request to fetch discord messages should work, but it requires a authorized user/bot member token. Is it fine for you to fetch the messages?

Comment: @TKperson No, fetching the message would as you said require additional authorization and add a whole new layer of complexity, and I'm only interested in using simple requests. But thank you for the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [this reddit post](https://reddit.com/r/Discord_Bots/comments/mxxjf0/delete_webhook/gvru2r7/):

> If you need to reference a message ID of a webhook message you sent, you can add ?wait=true to the end of the URL which will give you the message data (including the ID) instead of a 204 (No Content) when you don't include the query parameter.

So if you send your normal POST request to your url like this: `POST /webhooks/{webhook.id}/{webhook.token}`, add `?wait=true` to the end of that. Then you will get back data like this:

```json
{
    "id": "MESSAGEID",
    "type": 0,
    "content": "This is a test",
    "channel_id": "CHANNELID",
    "author": {
        "bot": true,
        "id": "AUTHORID",
        "username": "USERNAME",
        "avatar": "AVATARID",
        "discriminator": "0000"
    },
    "attachments": [],
    "embeds": [],
    "mentions": [],
    "mention_roles": [],
    "pinned": false,
    "mention_everyone": false,
    "tts": false,
    "timestamp": "2021-11-13T18:10:24.412000+00:00",
    "edited_timestamp": null,
    "flags": 0,
    "components": [],
    "webhook_id": "WEBHOOKID"
}
```